# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_lightning.core.decorators' | Google Colab GPU session

Tags: pytorch, importerror, pytorch-lightning

In my Google Colab GPU runtime, I try to install `pytorch_lightning`. So I do the following in the order:

```
!pip list | grep torch
torch                         2.0.0+cu118
torchaudio                    2.0.1+cu118
torchdata                     0.6.0
torchsummary                  1.5.1
torchtext                     0.15.1
torchvision                   0.15.1+cu118
```

Then using `!pip install pytorch_lightning`, I manage to install `2.0.1` version:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting pytorch_lightning
  Downloading pytorch_lightning-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (716 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 716.4/716.4 KB 34.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec[http]>2021.06.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (2023.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=5.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (6.0)
Collecting torchmetrics>=0.7.0
  Downloading torchmetrics-0.11.4-py3-none-any.whl (519 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 519.2/519.2 KB 48.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (4.5.0)
Collecting lightning-utilities>=0.7.0
  Downloading lightning_utilities-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.57.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (4.65.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (2.0.0+cu118)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=17.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pytorch_lightning) (23.0)
Collecting aiohttp!=4.0.0a0,!=4.0.0a1
  Downloading aiohttp-3.8.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.0/1.0 MB 71.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from fsspec[http]>2021.06.0->pytorch_lightning) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: triton==2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (3.10.7)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lit in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from triton==2.0.0->torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (16.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from triton==2.0.0->torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (3.25.2)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Downloading multidict-6.0.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (114 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 114.2/114.2 KB 17.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from aiohttp!=4.0.0a0,!=4.0.0a1->fsspec[http]>2021.06.0->pytorch_lightning) (22.2.0)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Downloading yarl-1.8.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (264 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 264.6/264.6 KB 32.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4.0,>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from aiohttp!=4.0.0a0,!=4.0.0a1->fsspec[http]>2021.06.0->pytorch_lightning) (2.0.12)
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3
  Downloading async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1
  Downloading frozenlist-1.3.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (158 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 158.8/158.8 KB 23.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2
  Downloading aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from jinja2->torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->fsspec[http]>2021.06.0->pytorch_lightning) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->fsspec[http]>2021.06.0->pytorch_lightning) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests->fsspec[http]>2021.06.0->pytorch_lightning) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from sympy->torch>=1.11.0->pytorch_lightning) (1.3.0)
Installing collected packages: multidict, lightning-utilities, frozenlist, async-timeout, yarl, aiosignal, aiohttp, torchmetrics, pytorch_lightning
Successfully installed aiohttp-3.8.4 aiosignal-1.3.1 async-timeout-4.0.2 frozenlist-1.3.3 lightning-utilities-0.8.0 multidict-6.0.4 pytorch_lightning-2.0.1 torchmetrics-0.11.4 yarl-1.8.2
```

Here's also to double check, if it's installed:

```
!pip list | grep torch
pytorch-lightning             2.0.1
torch                         2.0.0+cu118
torchaudio                    2.0.1+cu118
torchdata                     0.6.0
torchmetrics                  0.11.4
torchsummary                  1.5.1
torchtext                     0.15.1
torchvision                   0.15.1+cu118
```

However, I have a compatibility issue of importing a module:

```
import pytorch_lightning # works without error!
from pytorch_lightning.core.decorators import auto_move_data # ERROR!
```

which returns the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-6-2a2afba7b5b2> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from pytorch_lightning.core.decorators import auto_move_data

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_lightning.core.decorators'
```

I believe this module has been deprecated in the current version, does anyone know how to fix this compatibility issue?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto_move_data` has been deprecated with this [PR](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/pull/6993).

[Here](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/latest/upgrade/migration_guide.html) is the upgrade guide.

With PL 2.0, you need to import it like -

```py
import lightning L

class Model(L.LightningModule):
    ...

trainer = L.Trainer()
trainer.fit(Model(), dataloader)
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case I downgraded pytorch_lighting:

```bash
$ pip install pytorch_lightning==1.6.0
```